# Filtering Fields in SharePoint QueryString

Tags: microsoft-graph

I am trying to query a specific item from a SharePoint list. I have the following query string:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/myCompany.sharepoint.com:/sites/Global:/lists/%7MY_LIST%7D/items?expand=fields%28select%3DProduction_Code%29
```

This query returns a set of objects that looks like this:

```
"value": [
        {
            "@odata.etag": "\"000000-0000-4a29-0000-00000000,12\"",
            "createdDateTime": "2015-09-22T05:43:03Z",
            "eTag": "\"0000000-0000-0000-0000-00000000,12\"",
            "id": "0000",
            "lastModifiedDateTime": "2022-11-07T04:01:07Z",
            "webUrl": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/myCompany.sharepoint.com:/sites/Global:/lists/%7MY_LIST%7D/",
            "createdBy": {
                "user": {
                    "email": "user_email@gmail.com",
                    "displayName": "LastName, FirstName"
                }
            },
            "lastModifiedBy": {
                "user": {
                    "email": "user_email@gmail.com",
                    "displayName": "LastName, FirstName"
                }
            },
            "parentReference": {
                "id": "0000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000",
                "siteId": "my_company.sharepoint.com,000000-0000-00000-000000-0000000--0000000"
            },
            "contentType": {
                "id": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
                "name": "Generic E-Mail"
            },
            "fields@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#Collection(microsoft.graph.list)('%7MY_LIST%7D')/items('0000')/fields/$entity",
            "fields": {
                "@odata.etag": "\"000000-0000-4a29-0000-00000000,12\"",
                "Production_Code": "."
            }
        }]
```

Instead of all fields being returned, I want **JUST** the `fields` object, like below:

```
"fields": {
                "@odata.etag": "\"000000-0000-4a29-0000-00000000,12\"",
                "Production_Code": "."
            }
```

To achieve this, I tried the following query: 
[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/myCompany.sharepoint.com:/sites/Global:/lists/%7MY_LIST%7D/items?filter=fields%2FProduction_Code%20eq%20%27ARCH0090%27&select=fields](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/myCompany.sharepoint.com:/sites/Global:/lists/%7MY_LIST%7D/items?filter=fields%2FProduction_Code%20eq%20%27ARCH0090%27&select=fields%C2%A0)

However, the result set looks like so:

```
{
    "@odata.context": ""https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#Collection(microsoft.graph.list)('%7MY_LIST%7D')/items",
    "value": [
        {
            "@odata.etag": "\"000000-0000-0000-0000-0000000,11\""
        }
    ]
}
```

and omits fields that I requested as part of the query string. I have read through [Microsoft's Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/filter-query-parameter?tabs=java) exhaustively in search of why this happens, but with no luck. 
How do I create a query string that returns a `fields` object like so:

```
"fields": {
                "@odata.etag": "\"000000-0000-4a29-0000-00000000,12\"",
                "Production_Code": "."
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the expand and select queries like so:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items?expand=fields(select=Production_Code)
```